# JBoss RuntimeException: Could not resolve beanClass method for proxy call

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0

I'm working with EJB 3.0 and when I call the method to be executed, I get the error below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve beanClass method from proxy call
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.dynamicInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:274)
    at org.jboss.aop.Dispatcher.invoke(Dispatcher.java:106)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.invoke(AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.java:82)
    at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:809)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:608)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:406)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:173)
    at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:163)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1634)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:548)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.security.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessRemoteProxy.invoke(StatelessRemoteProxy.java:107)
    at $Proxy0.hayArchivosDisponibles(Unknown Source)
    at com.quartz.jobs.TrabajoPreguntarArchivosExistentes.execute(TrabajoPreguntarArchivosExistentes.java:63)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.security.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessRemoteProxy.invoke(StatelessRemoteProxy.java:107)
    at $Proxy0.hayArchivosDisponibles(Unknown Source)
    at com.quartz.jobs.TrabajoPreguntarArchivosExistentes.execute(TrabajoPreguntarArchivosExistentes.java:63)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
```

Anyone could help me please?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like your stateless session EJB has a problem with a transaction proxy, which is usually done by dynamically creating an aspect to do the work.  Have a look at your transaction annotations to see if they're correct.

Answer (score 2):

Got the same problem at a colleague's desk. He was working with JBoss AS (4.2.3).

Solved it by stopping the server, removing the cached deployment data at server_dir/tmp and server_dir/work and started again.

JBoss often gets confused in older versions when the same deployment unit has been redeployed several times.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem. The problem occurs after a change to the method signature and deployment, the previously deployed artifact is still somehow available in the classpath. Look carefully under JBoss's deploy, lib, work and tmp directories.